# Как такое реализовать?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать такой динамический скролл:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы иконка стрелки ездила сверху вниз?

Answer (score 2):

В общем я воспользовался бесплатным векторным редактором [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/ru/release/inkscape-0.92.4/) в котором нарисовал все эти элементы

1) Это обычный прямоугольник, с закруглением и `stroke-dasharray="60, 60"`

2) Это сама стрелка

3) Аннимировал на обычном css в поле defs style

> если что то не ясно спрашивайте

Вот таким образом это можно применить: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/EBdaxp

```html
<div style="width:135px;">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 30 60" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .arrow{
        animation:bullet 1s infinite alternate;
      }
      
      @keyframes bullet{
        0%{
          transform: translate(0, 3px);
        }
        100%{
         transform: translate(0, 0px);
        }
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
 <g transform="translate(0,-237)">
  <g transform="translate(0,1.5875)">
   <rect transform="scale(1,-1)" x="7.442934" y="-278.72717" width="15.523874" height="39.498867" rx="5.754787" ry="10" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-dasharray="80, 80" stroke-dashoffset="-3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" />
    
   <ellipse cx="15.189513" cy="246.14925" rx="1.0690781" ry=".93544334" stroke-width="0" />

   <path class="arrow" d="m22.798536 279.97082-7.564173 10.74066-7.5602862-10.10551m7.2767022-17.14844 0.283584 27.25395" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Что бы увеличить или уменьшить иконку то достаточно для item изменить `width`

Comment: Огромное спасибо вам Максим. !!!

Comment: А как можно видоизменить саму стрелочку? Мне она нужно более тонкая и острая?

Comment: @Роман если ответ Вам помог отметьте его как верный, пожалуйста

Comment: украл у тебя `@keyframes`, не стал мудрить

Answer (score 2):

Вот, пожалуйста, все что нужно знать, чтобы сделать подобное это команды `svg` атрибута `d` элемента `path`, тут использованы команды:

`M (MOVE)` перемещение на абсолютное значение

`m (move)` перемещение на относительное значение

`v (vertical)` вертикальная линия в относительных координатах

`l (line)` линия в относительных координатах

`a (arc)` дуга в относительных координатах

```html
<svg viewbox="-6 -6 12 30" height="90vh">
    <style>
      @keyframes arr {
        0%   {transform: translate(0, 3px)}
        100% {transform: translate(0, 0px)}
      }
    </style>
  <g fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round">
    <circle r="0.3"></circle>
    <path d="M0,5m0,10,a5,5,0,0,1,-5,-5v-10a5,5,0,0,1,10,0v10a5,5,0,0,1,-5,5z" 
          stroke-dashoffset="-5" stroke-dasharray="50 50"></path>
    <path d="M0,10v10m-2,-2l2,2l2,-2" style="animation: arr 1s infinite alternate"></path>
   </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: салам ты здесь ?

Comment: @MaximLensky да, я тут

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95868/js-community

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понял что вы хотите но чтобы зафиксировать объект используйте `position:fixed`

```css
.top-fixed {
 position: fixed;
 top: 150px;
 right: 0;
 background-color: #eee;
 padding: 3px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-fixed">Fixed element (Top)</div>
<p style="margin-bottom: 500px;">Filler text</p>
<p style="margin-bottom: 12000px;">Filler text</p>
```

Comment: Я хочу чтобы иконка стрелока которая изображена в круге спускалась с верху вниз. Некий эффект такой.

Comment: Предоставьте больше информации и код

Comment: Тут есть пример https://codepen.io/2xsamurai/pen/WwmjKQ

Comment: Да верно код этот я видел и он похож, но как имменно сделать так как на скриншоте чтобы не точка плавала а именно стрелочка ( Иконка)? И у меня нет кода. Потому что я даже не понимаю как это сделать(((

Comment: на `svg` достаточно не сложно

Comment: Если вы в этом не разбираетесь, то это сложно сделать. Во первых стрелка и иконка мышки должны быть отдельными. и на стрелку добавить эффект через keyframe.

Comment: Я просто вообще полный ноль в данном вопросе. Если кто может помогите сделать острее стрелочку. спасибо!

Comment: @Роман если хочешь я могу показать как это делать ..но и не только это ..любое другое любую форму ...

Comment: Хочу! Покажи пожалуйста!